# Reduce ND Vectors to 2D While Preserving Dot Product

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I am looking to reduce the dimensionality of a set (~500) of N dimensional vectors to 2D vectors, so that for any two vectors:

```
numpy.dot(vOriginal1, vOriginal2)==numpy.dot(vNew1, vNew2)
```

where vNew1, vNew2 are the dimensionally reduced vOriginal1, vOriginal2 vectors.

EDIT: I am not looking for an error of 0, just a low error. All the vectors are of fixed size M, and they are to be converted to size 2.

Comment: The norm of the  quantity `numpy.dot(vOriginal1, vOriginal2) - numpy.dot(vNew1, vNew2)` (across your data set), is called the reconstruction error of a dimensionality reduction algorithm or an embedding algorithm. Many algorithms such as isomap, multidimensional scaling, PCA and kernel PCA, and lots of other methods (you can find many in scitkit-learn), all attempt to minimize different formulations or approximations of this reconstruction error. You are asking for an algorithm that would guarantee a reconstruction error of exactly 0 for your data set, and generally this does not exist.

Comment: @ely: I am not looking for a 0 error, just low error.

Comment: Here is a link to the SKLearn implementations addressed by @ely http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure how this is even possible. The shape of the outputs is dependent on the N dimensions of the input vectors no?

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(range(0, 12)).reshape(6,2)
b = np.array(range(0, 12)).reshape(2,6)
np.dot(a,b)
c = a.reshape(4,3)
d = b.reshape(3,4)
np.dot(c,d)
```

gets us the following outputs:

```
a: 
 [[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]]  

b:
 [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]]

a dot b:
 [[  6   7   8   9  10  11]
 [ 18  23  28  33  38  43]
 [ 30  39  48  57  66  75]
 [ 42  55  68  81  94 107]
 [ 54  71  88 105 122 139]
 [ 66  87 108 129 150 171]]

a:
 [[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]

d:
 [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

c dot d:
 [[ 20  23  26  29]
 [ 56  68  80  92]
 [ 92 113 134 155]
 [128 158 188 218]
```

Can you tell us anything about the N-dimensional arrays? Are they a fixed size? Or a set of sizes?

Comment: The vectors are all of size M to start, and I want to convert them to size 2. Yes it is not possible to get an exact solution (because it doesn't exist). I am merely looking for an approximation.